# Passagem de Parâmetros de página HTML para ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma página asp.net a qual preciso obter parâmetros vindo de um *template* HTML. Estou tentando da forma abaixo mas não estou conseguindo pegar os valores. Segue meu código:

HTML - Template

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:61712/Default.aspx">

<TABLE>
<TBODY>
  <TR>
      <tdTEXT-ALIGN: center">
          <p><font size="3"><b>Solicitacao Nr. %NUMSC% </b></font> 
        <input type="hidden" name="NumeroSC" value="%NUMSC%" /> 

      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Minha página ASP.NET Default.aspx

```
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %> 

<script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(Object Src, EventArgs E)
        {
            string host = "******";
            string usuario = "******";
            string senha = "******";
            string banco = "******"; 

            var Compra = Request.Form["NumeroSC"];

            string strSQL = "SELECT codigo as Numero, arquivo from MeuDatabase where codigo like '%Compra%'"; // é dessa forma que pego o parametro na string? Já tentei também + Compra +             

            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + host + ";DATABASE=" + banco + ";UID=" + usuario + "; PWD=" + senha + ";");

            conexao.Open();  

      ...
```

Ao executar minha página ASP.NET, a página não retorna nenhum valor para a consulta. Já tentei no HTML em `value` passar um valor fixo existente mas também na minha consulta não retorna valor.

O que estou fazendo errado? Como consigo pegar corretamente esse parametro `%NUMSC%`?

**EDIT**

Esse formulário não é um submit, é um template. A cada nova solicitação é montada e arquivada um html, um para cada solicitação. Meu desejo é que a cada html que eu abrir eu chame a página asp.net com as informações daquele número de arquivo específico. 
Funciona assim: um usuário aprovador recebe um email com o link apontando para o html (nota fiscal). Eu queria que quando o usuário abrisse o link ele visse os dados que ele já vê atualmente mais um "framezinho" incorporado nesse html que é um href apontando para o anexo(documento) referente aquela fatura. A questão é que não posso editar o codigo do programa que gera a fatura para já trazer essas informações. Por isso vi a necessidade de criar uma página asp.net.

Comment: Olá. Você verifique no browser se o `value` do input está setado corretamente. Verifique também se o form está sendo submetido para a página, pois não vi nenhum input para fazer o submit.

Comment: eu já passei um value no input específico mas mesmo assim não deu. Esse formulário não é um submit, é um template. A cada nova solicitação é montada e arquivada um html, um para cada solicitação. Meu desejo é que a cada html que eu abrir eu chamar a página asp.net com as informações daquele número de arquivo específico.

Comment: Não entendi. Defina template. Qual o fluxo de execução? Quando esse formulário é submetido?

Comment: @CaiqueC. existe um programa que quando o usuário conclui a solicitação é gerada uma nota fiscal que é um HTML. Eu não posso mexer no código fonte dessa aplicação. Esse código que passei em cima é o template padrão das notas ficais. O que vai mudar em cada HTML gerado é o Numero da Solicitação e os outros campos. Então eu tenho um HTML (template) em branco e vários outros preenchidos com sua informações (Várias notas fiscais) Quando uma nova nota fiscal é gerada, eu recebo por email um link apontando para um desses respectivos html pronto com os dados.

Comment: @CaiqueC. O que eu preciso é que ao clicar e abrir o html eu resgate nele dados dessa página asp.net. O que estou tentando fazer primeiro é conversar o html com a página asp.net pra trazer as outras informações que preciso acrescentar a fatura.

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi bem, o que você faz é: após a conclusão da solicitação, é gerado um HTML a partir desse template, apenas com o número da solicitação preenchido.

O que você quer fazer é: após enviar esse HTML por e-mail e quando acessado, buscar mais dados a partir desse número que está no HTML e preencher o mesmo.

Estou certo? Se eu estiver, imagino três opções:

1. Criar o HTML já com todos os dados preenchidos (não vejo motivo para não faze-lo, a não ser que os dados não estejam de prontidão);
2. Enviar por e-mail um link apontando para uma página ASPX com o número da solicitação como parâmetro (exemplo: geranotafiscal.aspx?solicitacao=12345) e ao acessar você gera esse HTML com todas as informações, enviando para o usuário;
3. Da forma que você quer, tendo apenas o numero da solicitação num HTML e quando o usuário abrir, preencher os outros dados, imagino ser possível apenas com javascript, no evento de load fazer por ajax uma requisição para sua página, passando o parâmetro e tendo como retorno os dados desejados.

A última solução dará muito trabalho e terá o mesmo resultado da primeira. Se não puder fazer a primeira pelo motivo que citei ou algo parecido, faça a segunda.

As soluções apresentadas acima, consideram a necessidade do arquivo ser HTML, disponibilizando para download. Se for apenas para apresentação, crie um ASPX no formato da nota fiscal, com os labels e tudo mais, faça como na solução 2, passe um link do tipo notafiscal.aspx?solicitacao=12345 e no PageLoad, pegue o número da solicitação, busque os dados e preencha os labels.

Comment: obrigado @CaiqueC. É quase isso que voce entendeu, tirando o fato que quero carregar outros campos. Na verdade eu quero que apareça um novo campo que vai ser um link para um arquivo anexo. A questão é que não posso como falei mudar nada na geração do html. Tenho que pegar isso de uma forma a parte, no caso a página asp.net. A solução 2 acredito que me atenda sim. Como eu faço para passar esse link e receber no Pageload? Pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Desculpe, eu entendi que você mandava o e-mail com o link. Não é isso? Como é?

Comment: Sim, o usuário aprovador recebe um email com o link apontando para o html (nota fiscal). Eu queria que quando o usuário abrisse o link ele visse os dados que ele já vê atualmente mais um "framezinho" incorporado nesse html que é um href apontando para o anexo(documento) referente aquela fatura. A questão é que não posso editar o html padrão nem o programa que gera a fatura. Por isso vi a necessidade de criar uma página asp.net. Seria como chamar uma aplicação ao abrir o html.

Comment: O usuário recebe um link para a nota fiscal (HTML) e o que você quer fazer é que quando ele clique nesse link, ele veja a nota fiscal com mais uma informação (link para baixar o anexo)?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Precisa nem baixar, só visualizar. Vou subir todos os arquivos para o servidor de arquivos junto com a aplicação.

Comment: Mas é você que envia o e-mail? Se sim, a solução 2 é cabível, mas precisaria mudar o link enviado por e-mail, apontando para uma página sua, não para o HTML gerado e você também precisaria ter o numero da solicitação.

Comment: Não, o mesmo programa que gera a fatura envia o email. Eu só posso manipular o link vem no email, no caso o HTML

Comment: Eu não consigo através do html gerado abrir a minha página?

Comment: esse template padrão que eu falei seria o modelo através da qual todas as faturas são geradas e salvas. Minha ideia era nesse padrão apontar para minha página de modo que todos as demais faturas geradas sejam criadas e salvas apontando para minha aplicação de modo que sempre ao abri-las seja possível ver os arquivos anexos oriundos da nova página asp.net

Comment: Sendo HTML, sua única saída para processamento é JavaScript.

Comment: E sabe como seria um JavaScript pra isso? Continuaria precisando da página asp.net da mesma forma ne?

Comment: Não. Você teria que fazer um GET via JavaScript para uma url, passando o número da solicitação, tipo "dadossolicitacao.aspx?solicitacao=12345" que seria sua página asp.net. Ai no PageLoad, ou seja, quando bater na url, pega o numero da solicitação (QueryString), puxa os itens e retorna como Json. Ai no retorno dos dados você preenche o HTML, também com JavaScript. Não tenho conhecimento para te passar o código, mas sei que é simples. Pesquisa sobre como fazer um GET com Ajax e JQuery. links: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/, http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp.

Comment: Só lembrando que se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta.